# dspic30F grid sensing

Tags: voltage, pic, sensor, inverter

My question is about an inverter system with the transformer which is controlled by dspic30f, how to sense the mains voltage i.e.,230V 50Hz to the microcontroller?

Comment: By "sense" do you mean to tell if 230V is present, or do you want to measure it accurately?

Comment: If you want to check the presence, see my answer here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/328901/68606

Comment: just to know the presence of mains